# Modify state in nested object

Tags: swift, swiftui

im new to Swift and i am having this issue. I want to make a play/pause button in the toolbar and i decided to move the toolbar code to its own object `Toolbar`. The button should change its image when pressed but when i press it the state doesn't change. What am i doing wrong?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List{
                Text("asdf")
            }
            .toolbar {
                Toolbar()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Toolbar: ToolbarContent {
    @State var started = false
    
    var body: some ToolbarContent {
        ToolbarItem(id:"start-button", placement: .primaryAction) {
            Button(action: {
                self.started.toggle()
            }) {
                Image(systemName: self.started == true ? "pause.fill" : "play.fill")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `== true` is only ever necessary for optional Bools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@State` only works inside `View`s, and `ToolbarContent` isn't a `View`.

You should keep the `@State started` inside `ContentView`, and pass in its wrapped value to the toolbar. Then, use a closure to update it.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var started = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List{
                Text("asdf")
            }
            .toolbar {
                Toolbar(started: started) {
                    started.toggle() /// executed when `pressed` is called
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Toolbar: ToolbarContent {

    var started: Bool
    var pressed: (() -> Void) /// closure here!
    
    var body: some ToolbarContent {
        ToolbarItem(id:"start-button", placement: .primaryAction) {
            Button(action: {
                pressed() /// call the closure
            }) {
                Image(systemName: self.started == true ? "pause.fill" : "play.fill")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer that was fast :) One question, isn't it "wrong" to have that property in ContentView since it belongs to and will only be modified by `Toolbar` ?

Comment: @SantiagoAlvarez not at all - `started` doesn't only belong to Toolbar. Later on, you'll probably need to make more changes inside `ContentView` depending on whether it's `true` or `false`, for example, make the screen's background color green if started and red if not.

Comment: you can also set the action like this : ```Button(action: pressed){ //button view }```

Answer (score 3):

Use two-way binding.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var started = false //<-- Here
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List{
                Text("asdf")
            }
            .toolbar {
                Toolbar(started: $started) //<-- Here
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Toolbar: ToolbarContent {
    
    @Binding var started: Bool //<-- Here
    
    var body: some ToolbarContent {
        ToolbarItem(id:"start-button", placement: .primaryAction) {
            Button(action: {
                self.started.toggle()
            }) {
                Image(systemName: self.started ? "pause.fill" : "play.fill")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah nice (voted). I forgot `@Binding` isn't only for `View`.

Comment: This is the best answer